# Bootstrap 3 - Remove guttering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to remove the padding from one particular grid within Boostrap 3 -

I need to layout images responsively but the design requires no gaps between columns.

Comment: You can just add a rule for `padding: 0` or whatever using a media query.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 introduced `row-no-gutters` in v3.4.0

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters

Answer (score 1):

Yep you can do it by creating a custom style sheet and adding a additional css selector to the col class. [http://www.bootply.com/FtnGzu0dea][1]

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.thumbnails {
    padding: 0;
  }

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">

          <div class="col-md-3 thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>


  [1]: http://www.bootp
```

ly.com/FtnGzu0dea

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to add a class for removing the padding at a certain media query width.  Here is a test case that uses a header image that should respect the padding at all but the small size.  At that point it has no padding and fits the full width of the viewport.  I highly recommend using `@screen-xs-max` if you are compiling LESS source files.  It avoids the one pixel jump for media queries that use `max-width`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/htmn5Lov/

#### CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* replaced with @screen-xs-max if using LESS */
    .sm-no-padding [class*=col-] {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="row sm-no-padding">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/2000x1000"/>
        Image and/or content in a row where we remove the padding for small screens
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want more granular control with columns rather than at the row level, just apply the class to the columns and change your selector to `[class*=col-].sm-no-padding`

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new CSS class and add the following code into your stylesheet.

**Custom CSS:**

```
.no-padding > [class*='col-'] {
   padding-right:0;
   padding-left:0;
}
```

new CSS to use into your HTML `div`

```
.no-padding
```